# How to get values from dropdownlist to bind, when this dropdownlist is from a UserControl?

Tags: .net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, user-controls, bind

I have 3 dropdownlist (cbb_state, cbb_products, cbb_item) in my UserControl (UCProducs), which have a DataSource each one (ods_state, ods_products, ods_item), and I have my .aspx page, that is using this UserControl.... and this page has and ObjectDataSource that must bind the value from my 3 dropdownlist that are in my UserControl... I've tried some examples, but none of them helped me.

This is my UserControl code file:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Partial Class UCProducts
Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

Public Property Item() As Integer
    Get
        If cbb_item.SelectedValue <> "" Then
            Return cbb_item.SelectedValue
        Else
            Return 0
        End If
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        cbb_item.SelectedValue = value
        Distrito = fc_produts.value)
        If value > 0 Then
            cbb_products.Enabled = True

        End If
    End Set
End Property

Public Property State() As Integer
    Get
        If cbb_state.SelectedValue <> "" Then
            Return cbb_state.SelectedValue
        Else
            Return 0
        End If
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        If Not value = 0 Then
            cbb_state.SelectedValue = value

        End If

    End Set
End Property

Public Property Products() As Integer
    Get
        Return cbb_products.SelectedValue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        cbb_products.SelectedValue = value
    End Set
End Property




Private Function fc_pega_sub(ByVal index As Integer) As Integer

        'my code
End Function

Private Function fc_pega_distrito(ByVal value As Integer) As Integer

        'my code
End Function



Protected Sub cbb_regiao_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbb_regiao.SelectedIndexChanged
    'my code
End Sub
End Class
```

and in my .aspx page:

```
 <uc5:UCProduts ID="ucProd" runat="server" />
```

how do I do that?

Comment: It's not... n this project there's no 'model'

Comment: I appologize, but what exactly are you having an issue with?  Passing a datasource from the parent to the user control and binding?  Firing an event when the dropdownlist on the user control changes?  Getting the selected value from the user control to the parent page?  Or all?  Let me know and I can show you the correct way.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear... My problem here is: I can't get the select value from my 3 dropdownlist... each dropdownlist has its own ObjectDataSource, and they are on my UserControl... On my page .aspx I want to get the selected value from them and bind with the ObjectDataSourc of my .aspx page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it lol
So it's kind simple the answer... 
Because I have createad my Property "Products( )" when I put the UserControl in my page, I just had to reference the property binding my column!
Here is the solution:

```
<uc2:Products ID="Products" runat="server" Products='<%# Bind("fk_products") %>' />
```